# Select over multiple tables. Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to do this on my own but it looks like a dead end to me.

I am working under wordpress framework and with some custom tables.

The result i am trying to achieve is very simple but the way to get there is just too much for my head right now.

I need to select the top 50 results from tableOne based on the ammount of times that the id from tableOne is mentioned in tableTwo under some simple where conditions.

Using `$wpdb` class for the latest WordPress build, what can i use to achieve this?
Thanks

This is the Simple tableOne Query to get all posts:

`$allPosts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM pokeGrid_images WHERE status='0' ORDER BY tempo DESC LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset."");`

Now i need the first 50 results from this table, based on the number of times their id is mentioned on the second table with this structure: http://prntscr.com/byz2qw

Edit:

http://prntscr.com/byz79b

Note: Basically this is a forum, table one has the posts, table 2 the upvotes.
The expression must gather the most upvoted posts for the last X days.
If it was 1 post the expression would be `Select Count(*) FROM tableTwo Where tempo > then ".$variableWithUnixTimeDIff."`

column tempo is a `now()` timestamp.

Thanks

Comment: Add those simple conditions here, also add the code you have right now. What do you mean by "id from tableOne is mentioned in tableTwo"? Also add what kind of data is in tableOne, what kind of data is in tableTwo, add the table structure as well.

Comment: @Janno i added the query im using to gather all the posts and the structure of the second table.

Comment: Give me some sample data from both tables, give the other table structure as well. Then I can test it on my own system and see how to solve it.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with - implementing it using WP_Query, or with the SELECT statement itself? If the latter, then see to it that you get the statement working first in phpMyAdmin or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe I think he's having trouble with the SQL statement itself. He wants to know how to proceed.

Comment: @CBroe wp query is ok, i just dont know what is the best expression to gather the results.
Ill add the structure.

Comment: @Janno yes. Thanks ill add the structure

Comment: Best if you provide testable data using http://sqlfiddle.com/, plus exact description of what the expected output for this data should be.

Comment: @Janno added the structure

Comment: @CBroe added the structure

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Basically this is a forum, table one has the posts, table 2 the
>   upvotes. The expression must gather the most upvoted posts for the
>   last X days. If it was 1 post the expression would be Select Count(*)
>   FROM tableTwo Where tempo > then ".$variableWithUnixTimeDIff."

```
SELECT *, Sum(score) AS totalScore FROM tableTwo INNER JOIN tableOne ON tableTwo.memeID = tableOne.id GROUP BY memeID ORDER BY totalScore DESC;
```

Try this query.

//Edit - I just created a sample table with my own data. I only created the tableTwo, where this query did work:

```
SELECT *, Sum(score) AS totalScore FROM tableTwo GROUP BY memeID ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

So after that, just inner join data from tableOne and it will work!

Comment: Modified the query a bit.

Comment: If it doesn't work, please create the table with sample data to here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Modified my code again, tested it myself, it should work.

Comment: My advise to you, is to use better column names for id, also don't add column names like 'tempo', add stuff like pictureUploadDate on tableOne and on tableTwo, voteDate. About ID's, best way is to use tablename_id, so during inner joins, you still have access to both ID's.

Comment: Show me the output.